# Alternative to global arrays in C multithreading environment?

Tags: c, embedded

does anyone know about an elegant (efficient) alternative to using large global arrays in C for an embedded system, whereby the array is written to in an interrupt service routine and it is read elsewhere asynchronously:

I have no issues with the current implementation, however I was just wondering if it is the best option.

for example:

```
uint8_t array_data[20] = {0}; 
volatile bool data_ready = false; 

someIsr(void){

    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        array_data[i] = some_other_data[i]; 
     }
    data_ready = true; 

}

main(void){

 for(;;){
   
   if(data_ready){
   
      write_data_somewhere(&array_data[0]);
      data_ready = false;
   
   }


 }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: No. The best you can do is to provide a proper synchronization mechanism. A `volatile` flag  will provide a sufficient synchronization only if the access to it is atomic. `array_data` should be `volatile` to BTW.

Comment: No. For baseline/ISR communication [for an embedded system], using an array is [probably] the most efficient. But, if usage permits, I'd use a ring queue. So, you don't have to "slide" the array. You'd still need some atomic access (e.g. `stdatomic.h`) primitives. Or, baseline could do `cli()/sti()` wrappers around the critical section.

Comment: For a general discussion of techniques for eliminating globals in embedded systems see https://www.embedded.com/a-pox-on-globals/.  The points above about synchronisation, atomicity and buffering are all valid, but both give up on answering your question by answering "no" then discuss a different un-asked question.  I suggest the answer is "yes", and you really _should_ have a problem with the global.

Comment: Can you receive for example a 20 byte UART protocol without storing it? Absolutely, but then the protocol decoding has to be placed inside the ISR and you'll have to copy the data to wherever it needs to go from the ISR as well. This would be an extreme optimization for RAM use over execution speed.

Comment: More commonly, you'd use a higher level ring buffer ADT for such purposes. Which will take even more RAM than a dumb array, but provide easier means of access. Re-entrancy protection can be implemented inside the ring buffer itself too.

Comment: @CraigEstey You shouldn't use "cli" etc for the purpose of atomic access. That will shut down _all_ maskable interrupts on mosts MCUs and not just the one you need to block. Interesting way to get _very_ subtle, hard-to-find real-time bugs (been there done that). Instead use the specific interrupt disable functionality of the hardware peripheral.

Comment: @Lundin Well, since OP only specified "embedded" [no MCU arch, no OS], in context, I consider(ed) "cli" to be abstract.

Answer (score 0):

Using global arrays is often the best approach unless one would need to use the storage for other purposes when the interrupt routine isn't running.  An alternative is to use a global pointer to data that may be stored elsewhere, but one must be very cautious changing that pointer while interrupts are enabled.

An important caveat with your code, by the way: although the Standard regards the implications of a `volatile` qualifier as implementation-defined, allowing for the possibility that implementations may treat a volatile write as a potential "memory clobber", the authors of gcc require the use of compiler-specific intrinsics to prevent operations on "ordinary" objects from being reordered across operations on `volatile`-qualified ones.

For example, given:

```
volatile unsigned short out_count;
int *volatile out_ptr;
int buffer[10];

__attribute__((noinline))
void do_write(int *p, unsigned short count)
{
    __asm("");
    out_ptr = p;
    out_count = count;
    do {} while(out_count);        
    __asm("");
}

void test(void)
{
    buffer[0] = 10;
    buffer[1] = 20;
    do_write(buffer, 2);
    buffer[0] = 30;
    buffer[1] = 40;
    buffer[2] = 50;
    do_write(buffer, 3);
}
```

because the `__asm` intrinsics don't use gcc-specific syntax to indicate that they might "clobber" the contents of memory in ways the compiler can't understand (even though many compilers support the use of empty `__asm` intrinsics for that express purpose, and such intrinsics wouldn't really serve any other purpose), and because gcc can see that there's no way that `do_write` could alter the contents of `buffer`, it "optimizes out" the code that would store the values 10 and 20 into `buffer` before the first call to `do_write`.

Clang doesn't seem quite as bad as gcc.  It doesn't seem to reorder writes across volatile writes, it seems to refrain from reordering reads across functions that are not in-line expanded, and it seems to treat empty `asm` directives as potential memory clobbers, but I I'm not familiar enough with its documentation to know whether such restraint is by design, or merely a consequence of "missed optimizations" which might be "fixed" in future versions.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my top comment, one of best ways is to implement a ring queue.

Although I done a few ring queue implementations, here's one I just cooked up for illustration purposes. It is a [cheap] simulation of an Rx ISR for a uart [which is fairly common in embedded systems].

It is *fairly* complete, but I've not debugged it, so it may have some issues with the queue index calculations.

Anyway, here's the code:

```
// queue.c -- a ring queue

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

enum {
    QMAX = 1024
};

typedef unsigned char qdata_t;          // queue data item

typedef struct {
    int qenq;                           // index for enqueue
    int qdeq;                           // index for dequeue
    int qmax;                           // maximum number of elements in queue
    int qover;                          // number of queue overflows
    qdata_t *qbuf;                      // pointer to queue's buffer
} queue_t;

queue_t *rxisr_q;                       // pointer to Rx qeueue

// cli -- disable interrupts
void
cli(void)
{
}

// sti -- enable interrupts
void
sti(void)
{
}

// uart_ready -- uart is ready (has Rx data available)
int
uart_ready(void)
{
    int rval = rand();

    rval = ((rval % 100) > 95);

    return rval;
}

// uart_getc -- get character from uart receiver
int
uart_getc(void)
{
    int rval = rand();

    rval &= 0xFF;

    return rval;
}

// qwrap -- increment and wrap queue index
int
qwrap(queue_t *que,int qidx,int inc)
{
    int qmax = que->qmax;

    qidx += inc;

    if (inc > 0) {
        if (qidx >= qmax)
            qidx -= qmax;
    }
    else {
        if (qidx < 0)
            qidx += qmax;
    }

    return qidx;
}

// qavail_total -- total amount of space available (for enqueue)
int
qavail_total(queue_t *que)
{
    int qlen;

    qlen = que->qdeq - que->qenq;
    if (qlen < 0)
        qlen += que->qmax;
    qlen -= 1;

    return qlen;
}

// qavail_contig -- total amount of space available (for enqueue) [contiguous]
int
qavail_contig(queue_t *que)
{
    int qlen;

    qlen = que->qdeq - que->qenq;
    if (qlen < 0)
        qlen = que->qmax - que->qenq;
    qlen -= 1;

    return qlen;
}

// qready_total -- total amount of space filled (for dequeue)
int
qready_total(queue_t *que)
{
    int qlen;

    qlen = que->qenq - que->qdeq;
    if (qlen < 0)
        qlen += que->qmax;

    return qlen;
}

// qready_contig -- total amount of space filled (for dequeue) [contiguous]
int
qready_contig(queue_t *que)
{
    int qlen;

    qlen = que->qenq - que->qdeq;
    if (qlen < 0)
        qlen = que->qmax - que->qdeq;

    return qlen;
}

// qfull -- is queue full?
int
qfull(queue_t *que)
{
    int next;

    next = qwrap(que,que->qenq,1);

    return (next == que->qdeq);
}

// qpush -- push single value
int
qpush(queue_t *que,qdata_t chr)
{
    int qenq = que->qenq;
    int qnxt;
    int push;

    qnxt = qwrap(que,qenq,1);

    push = (qnxt != que->qdeq);

    if (push) {
        que->qbuf[qenq] = chr;
        que->qenq = qnxt;
    }

    return push;
}

// qalloc -- allocate a queue
queue_t *
qalloc(int qmax)
{
    queue_t *que;

    que = calloc(1,sizeof(*que));
    que->qbuf = calloc(qmax,sizeof(qdata_t));

    return que;
}

// uart_rx_isr -- ISR for uart receiver
void
uart_rx_isr(void)
{
    int chr;
    queue_t *que;

    que = rxisr_q;

    while (uart_ready()) {
        chr = uart_getc();

#if 0
        if (qfull(que)) {
            ++que->qover;
            break;
        }
#endif

        if (! qpush(que,chr)) {
            ++que->qover;
            break;
        }
    }
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int qlen;
    int qdeq;
    queue_t *que;

    rxisr_q = qalloc(QMAX);
    que = rxisr_q;

    while (1) {
        cli();

        qlen = qready_contig(que);

        if (qlen > 0) {
            qdeq = que->qdeq;
            write(1,&que->qbuf[qdeq],qlen);
            que->qdeq = qwrap(que,qdeq,qlen);
        }

        sti();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `translation unit` scope rather than global scope.  That is declare the array `static` in the translation unit in which it is used.  That translation unit should contain in this case the ISR that writes the data and an access function to read the data.  Anything else, including `main()` should be in other translation units in order that that do not have direct access to the array:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static volatile uint8_t array_data[DATA_LEN] = {0}; 
static volatile bool data_ready = false; 

void someIsr(void)
{
    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        array_data[i] = some_other_data[i]; 
    }
    data_ready = true; 
}

bool getdata( char* dest )
{
    bool new_data = data_ready ;

    if( data_ready )
    {
        memcpy( desr, array_data, sizeof(array_data) ) ;
        data_ready = false ;
    }
}
```

Then `main()` in some other translation unit might have:

```
#include "mydevice.h"

int main( void )
{
    uint8_t somewhare[DATA_LEN] = {0}; 
    for(;;)
    {
        if( getdata( somewhere ) )
        {
            // process new data
        }
    }
}
```

The above is based on your example, and the aim here is to isolate the array so that outside of the ISR the access is enforced to be read-only.  In practice it is likely that you will need a "safer" data structure or access method such as a critical-section, double-buffering or a ring buffer so that the data can be accessed without risk of it being modified while it is being read.

This is no less efficient that your original global access, it is simply a restriction of the visibility and accessibility of the array.