# TCC timer stops apparently without reason on ATXMEGA16E5

Tags: c, timer, interrupt, atmega

I hope you can help me with this very strange issue. I have synthesized my code as much as possible here.

On a statistic of 10 identical devices, the exact same issue happens on about half of them, while the others work without problems.

I use uart to send text commands to the ATXMEGA16E5.

Each text command is processed by “myFunction” that updates a specific value of the array “Values” at index “myIndex”.

Only when “myIndex” is equal to 3 and the “InputValue” function is executed (see the arrows on the right of the code), the TCC4 timer stops. Apparently, there isn’t any connection between the function and the timer.

If I turn off and then on and use the same device with all the other values of “myIndex” the issue does not arise.

I checked both “CommaIndex” and “InputValue” functions on a separate dummy C program and they are ok.

Thank you in advance.

```
#define BUFLEN 50       // for UART
#define CHARGE_LVLs     10 
char Rxbuf[BUFLEN];
volatile uint16_t Values[LVLs] = {12400, 4600, 2250, 1150, 430, 210, 15980, 15630, 15000, 13700};

int main(void)
{
    ...
    RTCInit();
    IRQInit(1, 1, 1);
    TimerInit();
    ...
    sei();
    
    while(1) 
    {
        ... 
        if(Rxflag==1)
        {
            if (strstr(Rxbuf, "myString,"))
                myFunction();
            Rxflag=0;
        }

    }
}

void myFunction()
{
    if(strstr(Rxbuf, ",abc,")) {myIndex=0; isUpdated = 1;}
    if(strstr(Rxbuf, ",def,")) {myIndex=1; isUpdated = 1;}
    if(strstr(Rxbuf, ",ghi,")) {myIndex=2; isUpdated = 1;}
    if(strstr(Rxbuf, ",lmn,")) {myIndex=3; isUpdated = 1;} // <------
    if(strstr(Rxbuf, ",opq,")) {myIndex=4; isUpdated = 1;}
    if(strstr(Rxbuf, ",rst,")) {myIndex=5; isUpdated = 1;}
    if(strstr(Rxbuf, ",uvz,")) {myIndex=6; isUpdated = 1;}
    if(strstr(Rxbuf, ",123,")) {myIndex=7; isUpdated = 1;}
    if(strstr(Rxbuf, ",456,")) {myIndex=8; isUpdated = 1;}
    if(strstr(Rxbuf, ",789,")) {myIndex=9; isUpdated = 1;}
    
    if(isUpdated == 1)
    {
        if(strstr(Rxbuf, WRITE_CALIB))
        {
            comma_index = CommaIndex(s, BUFLEN);
            if (InputValue(s, comma_index) > MAXVALUE) // <------
                Values[myIndex] = MAXVALUE;
            else
                Values[myIndex] = InputValue(s, comma_index);
            
            answ=1;
            UsartSendString(OK);
        }
    }
    
    UsartSendString("\r\n");
}

char CommaIndex(char s[], char strlength)
{
    int i;
    
    for(i=5; i<strlength; i++)  
        if (s[i] == ',')
        break;
    return (char)i;
}

uint16_t InputValue(char s[], char comma_index)
{
    return atoi(s+comma_index+1);
}

void IRQInit(char hi, char med, char lo) {
    PMIC.CTRL = (hi<<PMIC_HILVLEN_bp)|(med<<PMIC_MEDLVLEX_bp)|(lo<<PMIC_LOLVLEN_bp);
}

void RTCInit(void) {
    RTC.PER = 100;                              // 100ms
    RTC.INTCTRL = RTC_OVFINTLVL_MED_gc;         
    RTC.CTRL = RTC_PRESCALER_DIV1_gc;           // No prescaler
}

void TimerInit(void)
{
    TCC4.CTRLA =  TC_CLKSEL_DIV64_gc;           // CLKSEL=DIV64 : 32MHz/64=500KHz
    TCC4.PER = 4;                               // 500KHz/4 = 125KHz        @ 32 MHz
    TCC4.INTCTRLA = TC_CCAINTLVL_HI_gc;         // Int pri HI 
    TCC4.CTRLGCLR = 0b00000000;                 // Up direction
}

// *** Timer Overflow: 125KHz (8us) ***
ISR(TCC4_OVF_vect)
{
    if(emission)
    {
        PULSE_ON;
        
        emission = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        PULSE_OFF;
    }
    
    //************************************
    // Only for debug *********
    interruptCounter++;
    
    if (interruptCounter > 125000)
    {
        UsartSendString("Running");
        interruptCounter = 0;
    }
    //************************************

    TCC4.INTFLAGS = 1;
}
```

********************* UPDATE ***************************************

Sorry for my long silence but I needed some time to perform some tests suggested by **Craig Estey** that I sincerely thank for his kind attention.

I try to answer his questions and provide some comment and code for clarity.

“strstr is string func so it need a 0x00 terminator at the end” -> I forced the 0x00 terminator at the end of the string in RxBuf. The issue stays.

The format of the message sent to the atmega is: *cmnd,lmn,1000* where *cmnd* is always a 4 chars word, *lmn* is one of the combinations provided in myFunction (see above), *1000* is a number between 0 and 16383.

I know when the buffer has a full message checking the ‘\n’ char that is always present.

I am sure that *myFunction* is called once and it is undisturbed during the process for a given message. I doubled checked that.

Rx ISR does not drop incoming data, even when the issue occurs, because the *Values* array is correctly updated.

**What I have seen is:**

- If in `myFunction` the two `UsartSendString` lines are commented the issue does not occur.
- If in `UsartTxChar` I add the 1ms delay (see below), the issue does not occur even leaving the two `UsartSendString` lines in `myFunction` UNcommented. **This could be a solution actually, but I am not sure that it is the real solution and not simply a workaround.**

```
void
UsartInit(void)
{

    USARTC0.CTRLA = USART_DRIE_bm | USART_RXCINTLVL_MED_gc; // RX Int + Med pri
    USARTC0.CTRLB = USART_RXEN_bm | USART_TXEN_bm;  // RX & TX enable, Clk 1x
    USARTC0.CTRLC = USART_CMODE_ASYNCHRONOUS_gc | USART_CHSIZE_8BIT_gc; // Asynch, 8 bit, 1 stop, par none
    USARTC0.CTRLD = 0;                  // No encoding
    USARTC0.BAUDCTRLA = 51;             // BSEL
    USARTC0.BAUDCTRLB = 0b00100000;     // BSCALE 2 @ 32MHz
}

void
UsartTxChar(char b)
{
    USARTC0.DATA = b;

    _delay_ms(1);  // <---- THIS SOLVES THE ISSUE *****************

    while (!(USARTC0.STATUS & USART_TXCIF_bm)) {
    };

}

void
UsartSendString(char *b)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (b[i]) {
        UsartTxChar(b[i]);
        i++;
    }
}

ISR(USARTC0_RXC_vect)
{

    Rxchar = USARTC0.DATA;

    if (!Rxflag) {
        Rxbuf[Rxpnt] = Rxchar;
        Rxpnt++;
        if (Rxpnt == BUFLEN)
            Rxpnt--;
    }

    if (Rxchar == '\n') {
        Rxflag = 1;
        Rxpnt = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably have a race condition. There's so much that you're _not_ showing. The Uart Rx ISR. How/when `RxBuf` is filled and when/why `Rxflag` is set to 1. `strstr` is string func so it need a 0x00 terminator at the end. Does the ISR _guarantee_ this? What is the format of a message sent to the atmega? How do you know when the buffer has a full/complete message? Is it terminated by `\n`? How do you ensure that `myFunction` is _only_ called _once_ for a given message and that the message is complete? And, it will be undisturbed until after it is processed?

Comment: If `Rxflag` is a "gate" between ISR and `main`, I assume that the ISR will _not_ store new data until it sees that `Rxflag` is 0. What happens to incoming data in the ISR while `Rxflag` is 1? Is it just dropped/ignored? Are you checking for overflow of the uart Rx [internal] fifo? `strstr` is relatively slow and you're [needlessly] calling it many times, so I could easily see that it causes the Rx ISR to drop data. You probably need the buffer to be a ring queue. Or, implement a double buffering scheme. And, I'm having difficulty understanding how your parsing code works.

Comment: As stated above, sorry for my long silence but I needed some time to perform some tests suggested by @CraigEstey that I sincerely thank for his kind attention. I modified my post above to add information and clarify some aspects. Thank you again.

Comment: Assuming the UART H/W does _not_ need a delay, and the delay you propose "fixes" things, then I think you _do_ have a race condition. Your Rx ISR looks a bit fragile (i.e. prone to dropping data, etc. for edge cases--that are masked with the delay hack). I'm looking to speed up and correct the code, and will post an answer if I find something definitive. But, in the meantime, see my answer: [Alternative to global arrays in C multithreading environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64671916/5382650) for an example of a standalone UART/Rx ring queue implementation.

Comment: As to some UART code, see: https://gist.github.com/liludallasmp/4071d6628186ad9e420e It adds `USARTC0_STATUS = USART_TXCIF_bm;` to the end of the transmit char function (that your code doesn't do). Also, note the code for Rx ISR. See also: https://www.avrfreaks.net/s/topic/a5C3l000000UR83EAG/t118077

Comment: From the avrfreaks link, your Tx function should be: `while (!(USARTC0.STATUS & USART_DREIF_bm)); USARTC0.DATA = c;` AFAICT, in short, your bit mask value is incorrect. And, you need to check the status bit _before_ outputting to the data port (_not_ after).

Comment: @CraigEstey first, thank so much! Replacing the Tx function with the one that you suggested everything works great without any delay. In my opinion, it is the real solution, even if I do not understand why my previous implementation, that is actually the same of the 1st block of code you find in your avrfreaks link, triggers the issue.

Comment: Together with my colleagues, I implemented it in several projects and I have never had a problem with it. I am reading now the Getting Started with USART (https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/TB3216-Getting-Started-with-USART-90003216A.pdf) and at p. 8 I see: Before sending data, the user needs to check if the previous transmission is completed by checking the USARTn.STATUS register. It also provides the code. This would suggest that your way is the right one.

Comment: So, if you agree, you can write your answer, providing a little bit of explanation, and I will be glad to mark it as the answer of this discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, if you agree, you can write your answer, providing a little bit of explanation, and I will be glad to mark it as the answer of this discussion. –
> user1941332

Okay. Most of this was covered in the top comments.

If adding a delay to code that intermittently fails "fixes" the issue, then this means the program isn't fixed. The real issue is just masked.

Here is your transmit code:

```
void
UsartTxChar(char b)
{
    USARTC0.DATA = b;

    _delay_ms(1);                       // <---- THIS SOLVES THE ISSUE *****************

    while (!(USARTC0.STATUS & USART_TXCIF_bm)) {
    };

}
```

[Correct USART Transmit Function](https://www.avrfreaks.net/s/topic/a5C3l000000UR83EAG/t118077) points out the issue. We must spin on the status register, waiting for the transmit buffer to clear *before* we output a new character to the transmitter.

And, the status bit you were testing wasn't the correct one. Here is the refactored code:

```
void
UsartTxChar(char b)
{

    while (! (USARTC0.STATUS & USART_DREIF_bm));

    USARTC0.DATA = b;
}
```